# Number of zeros of a sum of Shah functions by applying Rice's formula?

Tags: fourier-series

There is a *Dirac pulse train* following the scheme of the *Shah function* (or *$\delta$-cumb function*) with its Fourier series of the form:

$$\varsigma(t,T)=\sum_{n=-\infty}^{\infty}\delta (t-nT)=\frac{1}{T}\sum_{n=-\infty}^{\infty}\exp\left(\frac{i 2\pi n t}{T}\right)$$

here $n\in \Bbb Z$; $t$ time and $T(\in \Bbb N)$ the period between the pulses, which occur exactly at the levels of the integers.

The sum of $\varsigma(t,T)$ over $T$ in a given range $[1,T_{\max}]$ and $n$ in a range $[1,T]$ (instead) is accordingly:

$$S(t,T_{\max})=\sum_{T=1}^{T_{\max}}\varsigma(t,T)=\sum_{T=1}^{T_{\max}}\frac{1}{T}\sum_{n=1}^{T}\exp\left(\frac{i 2\pi n t}{T}\right)$$

And the zeros (at the level of some integers) of this function with respect to $t$, hence:

$$\sum_{T=1}^{T_{\max}}\frac{1}{T}\sum_{n=1}^{T}\exp\left(\frac{i 2\pi n t_0}{T}\right)=0$$

***The Question*** *is to identify the number of such zeros $\mathcal Z$ in a range of $t\in[T_{\max},T_{\max}^2]$ by applying [Rice's formula](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rice%27s_formula#cite_note-barnett-6), while assuming that the frequencies $1/T$ are rationally independent?*

Comment: Why in the definition of $S$ the interior sum is $\sum_{n=1}^T$ and not $\sum_{n=-\infty}^\infty$? And which frequencies are rationally independent? The variable $T$ was assumed to be integer.

Comment: The boundaries are indeed $[1,T]$ although generally Shah defined over infinities. $T$ is an integer, yes and its inverse is meant by frequencies.

Comment: Are $t,t_0$ integers or is $t$ (time) continuous? Could you explain the sentence: "And the zeros (at the level of some integers) of this function with respect to t, hence:"

Comment: yes. We are only interested in $t$ and $t_0$ integers. Sorry if the sentence was raising confusion but it should say that we are only interested in the integers. The Shah function has zeros elsewhere, which are not interesting for us, the same for its superpositions.

Comment: So $S(t,T_{max})$ counts the number of divisors of $t$ that are $\le T_{max}$, and $t_0$ is a zero if it is co-prime to all integers $\le T_{max}$. Thus, the question is: apply Rice's formula to count the number of integers between $T_{max}$ and $T_{max}^2$ that are co-prime to all integers $\le T_{max}$. Is that correct?

Comment: For $t,t_0,T,T_{max}\in \mathbb{N}$,

$$\frac{1}{T}\sum_{n=1}^{T}\exp\left(\frac{i 2\pi n t}{T}\right)=\cases{1&$T|t$\cr 0 &otherwise\cr}$$ but then how can $$\sum_{T=1}^{T_{\max}}\frac{1}{T}\sum_{n=1}^{T}\exp\left(\frac{i 2\pi n t_0}{T}\right)=0.$$ If $(T=1)|t_0$? If the sum began at $T=2$ I'd be tempted to say that $\mathcal{Z}$ was the number of primes in the interval...

Comment: One other thing I don't get, in your second equation you are equating a Dirac delta comb ($\infty$ at multiples of $T$) with what is effectively a Kronecker Delta comb (1 at multiples of $T$), how does that work? This was also the issue Andrew was raising I believe..

Comment: Ok, so you are interested in the finite sum but you cannot write in the middle equation that it is equal to the infinite sum because it is not. What about the issue about starting the final sum at $T=1$? Do you agree there are no integer solutions to that equation?

Comment: @GrahamHesketh as mentioned before, you are even welcome to change $T$. For $T=1$ or any other integer you like $T=?$ the question is to show the number of zeros through Rice's formula. I am interested in the method being applied to this and calculate the zeros in the superposition of such trails. I must discontinue this discussion as this is not a chatroom.

Answer (score 1):

This is ***not a complete answer*** in that it does not apply Rice's formula although it does derive the formula for the counting function $\mathcal{Z}(T_{max})$.

For $t,t_0,T,T_{max}\in \mathbb{N}$:

$$\frac{1}{T}\sum_{n=1}^{T}\exp\left(\frac{i 2\pi n t}{T}\right)=\cases{1&$T|t$\cr 0 &otherwise\cr}$$
so:

$$S(t,T_{\max})=\sum_{T=1}^{T_{\max}}\frac{1}{T}\sum_{n=1}^{T}\exp\left(\frac{i 2\pi n t}{T}\right)$$
counts the number of divisors of $t$ that are $\le T_{max}$ and $t_0$ is defined to be a zero if it satisfies: 
$$\sum_{T=1}^{T_{\max}}\frac{1}{T}\sum_{n=1}^{T}\exp\left(\frac{i 2\pi n t_0}{T}\right)=\sum_{T=1}^{T_{\max}}\cases{1&$T|t_0$\cr 0 &otherwise\cr}=0 \tag{1}$$
which holds iff $t_0$ is not divisible by any integer $1\le T\le T_{max}$. However $t_0$ is always divisible by $1$ so the sum in $(1)$ must always evaluate to something $\ge1$ for any $T_{max}$. In which case we are forced to say

*there are no integers $t_0,\,T_{max}$ such that $(1)$ holds and thus:*
$$\mathcal{Z}(T_{max})=0, \,\forall T_{max}\in \mathbb{N}.\tag{2}$$

Alternatively, if we chose to exclude the trivial case in which $1$ divides all integers by beginning the outer sum in $(1)$ at $T=2$ we may find a less trivial outcome. Define $t_0$ with $2\le T_{max}\le  t_0\le T_{max}^2$ to be a solution to the equation:
$$\sum_{T=2}^{T_{\max}}\frac{1}{T}\sum_{n=1}^{T}\exp\left(\frac{i 2\pi n t_0}{T}\right)=0$$
then $\mathcal{Z}$ counts the number of integers $t_0 \in \left[T_{max},T_{max}^2\right]$ such that $T\nmid t_0 \forall\, 2\le T \le T_{max}$, in which case:
$$\mathcal{Z}=\pi(T_{max}^2)-\pi(T_{max}) \tag{3}$$
where $\pi(x)$ is the prime counting function.

*Proof*

If: $$\exists t_0 \,\, \text{such that} \,\,\,T\nmid t_0 \,\forall\, 2\le T \le T_{max},$$ but $t_0$ is not prime, then: $$\exists k>T_{max}\,\, \text{such that} \,\,k|t_0,$$ and:
 $$\exists n=\dfrac{t_0}{k}>T_{max},n\in \mathbb{N},$$
which implies:
$$t_0=nk>T_{max}^2,$$
from which we conclude that $t_0 \in \left[T_{max},T_{max}^2\right]$ is not a solution when $t_0$ is not prime. It is clear that if $t_0$ $\left(2\le T_{max}\le  t_0\le T_{max}^2\right)$ is prime, it is not divisible by $2\le T \le T_{max}$ and is therefore a solution, unless $T_{max}$ is itself prime. From this we conclude that all $t_0$ are primes such that $T_{max}<t_0\le T_{max}^2$ and $(3)$ follows.

Comment: Appreciate your insights, this is of course interesting but unfortunately not a response to my question. The question was not a mathematical reformulation of the sieve of Erathostenes that is resulting from here in case of starting $T=2$ and applying the roots of unity method with the number theoretical function (for counting solutions). This has been studied extensively elsewhere in literature. The problem to me is to solve a signal processing problem of superposition of pulse trains in a discrete (integer) acting system and whether Rice's formula provides a method of approximation.

Comment: I wonder, whether your answer would not have a good chance on the following question raised ten days ago. There is a bounty on: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/447229/sieves-of-category-eratosthenes-and-the-prime-sequence-recurrence-relation

Comment: I am migrating this to dsp.SE. If you get an account there, you will get reputation there.